# Domains of NSError object

Tags: ios, nserror

I have a website called mysite.com with a Payment API like Stripe. I am building an SDK, and trying to figure out the proper names for NSError error domains. Any SDK errors (i.e client-side validation errors) are in the MySiteSDKDomain. Any site API errors (errors from mysite.com) are in the MySiteAPIDomain.

What is the convention for these NSError domain names?